# Swift: 'Int' is not convertible to 'ObjCBool'

Tags: objective-c, swift, compiler-errors, compiler-bug, xcode6.4

In my code I have a lazy var:

```c
lazy var myService = {
    return JSObjection.defaultInjector().getObject(MyService) as? MyService
}()
```

In the same file I try to call a function of `myService`:

```c
func foo() {
    myService?.getSomeStringsFrom(nil)
}
```

MyService is defined in an Objective-C source file:

```c
@interface MyService : NSObject
- (NSArray *) getSomeStringsFrom:(NSString *)aString;
@end

@implementation MyService
- (NSArray *) getSomeStringsFrom:(NSString *)aString {
    return nil;
}
@end
```

The code cannot be compiled because the call of `getSomeStringsFrom(nil)` triggers an error message (twice):

```c
<unknown>:0: error: 'Int' is not convertible to 'ObjCBool'
```

This does not make sense - I am doing the same with other services and XCode does not complain about it. Is it a compiler bug? I am using XCode 6.4 and Swift 1.2.

EDIT: After more digging in the code I found out that the error message can also be triggered by instantiating `MyService`. In the following answer, you will see the real "root" of the problem.

Comment: Can you post your code about the `getSomeStringsFrom`?

Comment: @Bannings I just did. Basically, the implementation seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: It looks like somewhere in the code is a check e.g.  `if (intValue) {}` which is valid in C/Objective-C but not in Swift

Comment: Are you using the `myService?.getSomeStringsFrom(nil)` in an if statement?

Comment: @Bannings Actually no, the result is not used, at all.

Comment: Just a test. What happen if you add `__nullable` to the signature of `getSomeStringsFrom`? I mean: `- (NSArray *) getSomeStringsFrom:(NSString * __nullable)aString`

Comment: @appzYourLife Actually, `__nullable` changes nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listed Objective-C file was incomplete. At the beginning, there was one crucial enum definition which broke the compilation process as soon as the file was used from within my Swift code:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(BOOL, Stuff) {
    StuffX = YES,
    StuffY = NO
};
```

Apparently, Swift dislikes `BOOL` when it comes to enums. I do not know why but as soon as I convert `BOOL` to `Boolean` the error vanishes.

Comment: Thank you for this hint, I completely forgot to do this.